# VLC opening when inserting audio CD despite autoplay being disabled

Tags: gnome-shell, cd, media, autoplay

Whenever I insert an audio CD, VLC opens, despite the CD Audio action in Settings/Removable Media being set to “Do nothing”.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome-shell.

How can I prevent VLC from opening?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `.config/mimeapps.list` for a line(s) `x-content/audio-cdda=` remove the line(s), log out/in & see..

Comment: @doug Nothing in that file appears to match VLC or CD audio unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, are you using the snap vlc or the .deb version/ (- `snap list` or  `snap show vlc` show be informative.

Comment: I'm using the version from the Ubuntu repositories. I don't have anything installed with snap.

Comment: I could show you this easier in a forum but do this. Open up system settings > details > removalable media & also open up dconf-editor & navigate to `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling`. There can 3 `autorun-x-content` settings that will correspond to the available choices in settings (Ask me option is default, i.e nothing set for cdda elsewhere.)  See which setting/key has  `x-content/audio-cdda`  in it (if any, though based on what you say happens it should be in the `autorun-x-content-start-app` one.)  In the details window make some changes, see if they are reflected in dconf..